# Keyboard spell word mysterious subtract 1

Tags: python

This code produces the "path" to spell out a word in an alphabet of a certain width. For example, with width of 4, the alphabet is like so

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
q r s t
u v w x
y z
```

and to spell `"dog"` the path produced (starting from `a`) is 
`R R R ! L D D D ! U U !` where `!` is to select the character. With a width of 3 an alphabet below is produced and to spell `"dog"` has the path

`D ! D D D R R ! L L U U !`

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
j k l
m n o
p q r
s t u
v w x
y z
```

I am looking at someone's solution on how to solve this problem and I can't figure out why the minus 1 occurs in  `ord(previous_char) - 1` as well as `ord(word[idx]) - 1`. It seems a bit mysterious to me. I assume it has to the coordinate system somehow. The subtract 1 makes a huge difference on starting the path at the `a` but I unsure why.

```
import math

def walk_keyboard(width, word):
    res = []
    for idx in range(len(word)):
        # find the x and y coordinates of the previous character
        # if there was no previous letter, use 'a'
        previous_char = word[idx - 1] if idx > 0 else 'a'
        previous_ord = ord(previous_char) - 1
        previous_x = previous_ord % width
        previous_y = math.floor(previous_ord / width)

        # find the x and y coordinates of the current character
        current_ord = ord(word[idx]) - 1
        current_x = current_ord % width
        current_y = math.floor(current_ord / width)

        if current_y < previous_y:
            res += ['U'] * int(previous_y - current_y)

        if current_x < previous_x:
            res += ['L'] * int(previous_x - current_x)

        if current_y > previous_y:
            res += ['D'] * int(current_y - previous_y)

        if current_x > previous_x:
            res += ['R'] * int(current_x - previous_x)

        res.append('!')
    return ' '.join(res)

print(walk_keyboard(4, 'dog'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this `- 1` is a hack for the script to work.

It seems to me that the `- 1` is used to match the index of the first column (0) and the `% width`.

It works as well for `- 97` (`ord('a') = 97`) but not for width 5. The coordinates based on Unicode (`ord`) is a bit weird for this problem, you should have a custom function to get the index of a letter in the alphabet. Then you won't have this kind of hacks.

Something like:

```py
def get_index_in_alphabet(letter):
  alphabet = 'abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  return alphabet.index(letter)
```

EDIT:

Furthermore, to ensure your script is really working, you can have unit tests. Because I am not sure it currently works for every word.

Comment: You don't need to define `alphabet`. That's the same as [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase). And for the index I prefer `ord(character) - ord('a')`.

Comment: Didn't know the existence of `string.ascii_lowercase`, thx. Concerning getting the index via Unicode, it seems a bit overkill to me. Depends if you consider having letters with accents.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun an alternative solution.

```
import string


def subtract_tuples(t1, t2):
    return tuple(v1 - v2 for v1, v2 in zip(t1, t2))


def get_moves(options, diff):
    return options[diff >= 0] * abs(diff)


def walk_keyboard(matrix_width, word):
    word = [char for char in word.lower() if char in string.ascii_lowercase]
    way = ''
    current_position = (0, 0)
    for character in word:
        target_position = divmod(ord(character) - ord('a'), matrix_width)
        diff_vertical, diff_horizontal = subtract_tuples(target_position, current_position)
        vertical_moves = get_moves('UD', diff_vertical)
        horizontal_moves = get_moves('LR', diff_horizontal)
        way += horizontal_moves + vertical_moves + '!'
        current_position = target_position
    return way


def main():
    words = 'dog', 'stackoverflow', 'abcfedghilkj'

    for word in words:
        for matrix_width in range(3, 7):
            way = walk_keyboard(matrix_width, word)
            print(' '.join(way))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

And now for some really evil stuff. ;) A one-liner:

```
def walk_keyboard2(matrix_width, word):
    return ''.join('L' * max(divmod(ord(current) - ord('a'), matrix_width)[1] - divmod(ord(target) - ord('a'), matrix_width)[1], 0) + 'R' * max(divmod(ord(target) - ord('a'), matrix_width)[1] - divmod(ord(current) - ord('a'), matrix_width)[1], 0) + 'U' * max(divmod(ord(current) - ord('a'), matrix_width)[0] - divmod(ord(target) - ord('a'), matrix_width)[0], 0) + 'D' * max(divmod(ord(target) - ord('a'), matrix_width)[0] - divmod(ord(current) - ord('a'), matrix_width)[0], 0) + '!' for current, target in zip('a' + word, word))
```

Yes, it's a very long line and I would **never** use this in production code.